# TF2 object detection finetuning - change input image size?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api, tensorflow2.x

I am trying to finetune a pretrained model from [TensorFlow 2 Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md), say "EfficientDet D0 512x512", which outputs bounding boxes for multiple objects in the same image.

But my KITTI dataset images are about 1200x400.
Hence, resizing 1200x400 to 512x512 is **really awkward** and causes a huge loss of information. Using the other sizes, like 800x800 or 1024x1024 are equally problematic, because of the square aspect ratio.

There have been not so useful [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1876) threads.

And everyone just tells you to resize the images to a smaller size in the `pipeline.config` file like this:

```
image_resizer {
  fixed_shape_resizer {
    height: 300
    width: 300
  }
}

image_resizer {
  keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
    min_dimension: 300
    max_dimension: 300
  }
}
```

But that is not something I want to do.

Keras is so convinient in this case, because you can simply mention the input tensor size while loading the pretrained model and voila.

```
model = VGG16(weights="imagenet",
           include_top=False,
           input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))
```

So, is there a way to change the input tensor shape of the TF2 model zoo files?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you change the input size in the image resizer does it throw any error?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the version of the network on TFHub? That version has no specified input size (it takes images of size (1, None, None, 3) ). Then, you can use the pretrained network on your own dataset of images, whatever size they may be.

```
image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(tf.io.read_file(path))
image = tf.reshape(image, shape=(1,1200,400,3))
detector = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/efficientdet/d0/1")
detector_output = detector(image)
```

EfficientDet D0 is available on TF hub at https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/efficientdet/d0/1.

Comment: Thanks for the TF Hub idea, but I just spent a few hours trying to make TF Hub model object work.